# Check that AJAX retrieved images are all loaded first

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, imagesloaded

When loading in html with AJAX, how can I check that all images within that HTML are fully loaded before doing "something" (like showing them).

I have tried a selection of ways, including the 'imagesloaded' plugin.

```
var page = 'P40',
    path = 'http://www.domain.com/gallery/embed-items/'+page;

$.get(path, function(data) {

    $(data).imagesLoaded( function() {

    $('#gallery-masonry').append($.parseHTML(data));

        $galleryContainer.masonry("reloadItems");
        $galleryContainer.masonry();

    });

});
```

The html that is set into 'data' is around 20 like the following:

```
<div class="grid col-12 bp1-col-6 bp2-col-4 bp3-col-3 item gallery-item half-divide">

    <img srcset="http://www.domain.com/images/uploads/gallery/Venice_Lagoon_Sunrise_2_Jan_2016-1550.jpg, http://www.domain.com/images/uploads/gallery/Venice_Lagoon_Sunrise_2_Jan_2016-1550.jpg 2x" title="Venice Lagoon Sunrise" alt="Venice Lagoon Sunrise">

</div>
```

NEW

```
$.get(path, function(data) {

    var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(""); // you could also use DOMParser, but parsing HTML is supported only in modern browsers.
    doc.body.innerHTML = data; // write the data to document

    var images = doc.querySelectorAll("img"), // get all images, you can specify only some though by particular selector
        amount = images.length; // inital length

    [].forEach.call(images, function(img) { // loop over images
        img.onload = function() { // bind the listener

            amount--; // ok one item was loaded, we decrease the amount

            if (amount === 0) { // if amount is equal to 0, it means the images are loaded

                $('#gallery-masonry').append(body);

                $galleryContainer.masonry("reloadItems");
                $galleryContainer.masonry();

            }

        };

    });

    var body = $('body')[0].appendParent(doc.querySelector("body")); // attach the content of body (the data you received).

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an event fired when the image is loaded - it's called "load". You can use it and attach it to all the images you receive. You should bind that event listener before the images are added to DOM (it means before their download isn't run yet).

Example:

```
var page = 'P40',
path = '/';

$.get(path, function(data) {
  var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(""); // you could also use DOMParser, but parsing HTML is supported only in modern browsers.
  doc.body.innerHTML = data; // write the data to document

  var images = doc.querySelectorAll("img"), // get all images, you can specify only some though by particular selector
      amount = images.length; // inital length

  [].forEach.call(images, function(img) { // loop over images
    img.onload = function() { // bind the listener
      amount--; // ok one item was loaded, we decrease the amount
      if (amount === 0) { // if amount is equal to 0, it means the images are loaded
        // images loaded
      }
    };
  });

 // loop over the content of body (it wraps your content) and add each child of it
  [].forEach.call(doc.body.children, function(child) {
    document.body.appendChild(child); 
  });
});
```

Rework of your code

```
$.get(path, function(data) {
    var container = $('#gallery-masonry')[0]; // container for images

    var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(""); // you could also use DOMParser, but parsing HTML is supported only in modern browsers.
    doc.body.innerHTML = data; // write the data to document

    var images = doc.querySelectorAll("img"), // get all images, you can specify only some though by particular selector
        amount = images.length; // inital length

    [].forEach.call(images, function(img) { // loop over images
        img.onload = function() { // bind the listener

            amount--; // ok one item was loaded, we decrease the amount

            if (amount === 0) { // if amount is equal to 0, it means the images are loaded    
                container.style.display = "";
                $galleryContainer.masonry("reloadItems");
                $galleryContainer.masonry();

            }

        };

    });

    container.style.display = "none";
    [].forEach.call(doc.body.children, function(child) {
       container.appendChild(child); 
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you Jakub. I have been looking through your code to understand how it works. I have added a 'NEW' code into my question using yours. I am appending the loaded data into another div. As it stands, it is adding the data wrapped in 'body'. Is there a way I can load the data and append it without the wrapping of 'body'?

Comment: @ccdavies, it was my bad actually. I've just updated the code. Basically you must loop over the bodie's children and attach each of it to the document.body of your document.

Comment: Thank you, but I am still unsure how I would then append this as in my 'NEW' code. I tried adding your amended code as a variable, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Jakub. The issue here is that I need the code be appended only once all images have loaded, then run the masonry code. I think what happens in your forked code is the html is appended after the masonry code is run. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @ccdavies, there is a way. You could hide the container, fill the content, wait until images are loaded and then show it again and trigger masonry. See the new code.

Comment: This doesn't append the items, and also hides the entire selection when appending.

Comment: Is there a way to append the loaded data only after the images have all loaded?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111358/discussion-between-jakub-rozek-and-ccdavies).